# Como fazer com que a mensagem do Toastr apareceça e somente depois execute o relaod da página?

Tags: javascript, funções, formulário

O cadastro é realizado com sucesso, porem a página da reload antes de aparecer a mensagem do Toastr.

```
// Função formulário de cadastro de Cliente  
function cadIndCliente(btnPropToggler) {


    // Variáveis criadas para receber as informações dos inputs do formulário de cadastro do cliente
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome");
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var dddTelefone = document.getElementById("dddTelefone");
    var numeroTel = document.getElementById("numeroTel");
    var infoAdicional = document.getElementById("infoAdicional");

    // Armazena todas as variáveis em uma única variável
    var dados = {

        'nome': nome.value,
        'email': email.value,
        'dddTelefone': dddTelefone.value,
        'numeroTel': numeroTel.value,
        'infoAdicional': infoAdicional.value,

    }

    // Converte valores em javascript para uma String JSON
    var dadosForm = JSON.stringify(dados);

    // Envia as informações do formulário atráves de AJAX para o arquivo
    $.ajax({

        url: 'teste.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { data: dadosForm },

        // Retorno se tudo ocorreu normalmente
        success: function (result) {

            // codigo...

        },
        // Retorno caso algum erro ocorra
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            // codigo...

        }

    });

    toastr.info('Cadastro de cliente realizado com sucesso!')

    // Após clicar no botão cadastrar imóvel da um reload na página
    sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", "true");
    document.location.reload();    

}
```

Comment: Veja o onHidden e onClick aqui > https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr#callbacks
No callback você pode dar o refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver aplicando na função setTimeout um tempo de 800 Milissegundo, desta forma a função leva alguns Milissegundo para ser executa e o Toastr mostrar sua menagem.

Utilizando o setTimeout() para definir um intervalo antes de executar o reload da página.

```
// Função formulário de cadastro de Cliente  
function cadIndCliente(btnPropToggler) {


    // Variáveis criadas para receber as informações dos inputs do formulário de cadastro do cliente
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome");
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var dddTelefone = document.getElementById("dddTelefone");
    var numeroTel = document.getElementById("numeroTel");
    var infoAdicional = document.getElementById("infoAdicional");

    // Armazena todas as variáveis em uma única variável
    var dados = {

        'nome': nome.value,
        'email': email.value,
        'dddTelefone': dddTelefone.value,
        'numeroTel': numeroTel.value,
        'infoAdicional': infoAdicional.value,

    }

    // Converte valores em javascript para uma String JSON
    var dadosForm = JSON.stringify(dados);

    // Envia as informações do formulário atráves de AJAX para o arquivo
    $.ajax({

        url: 'teste.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { data: dadosForm },

        // Retorno se tudo ocorreu normalmente
        success: function (result) {

            // codigo...

        },
        // Retorno caso algum erro ocorra
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            // codigo...

        }

    });

    // Mensagem do Toast para informar que cadastro foi realizado com sucesso
    toastr.info('Cadastro de cliente realizado com sucesso!')

    // Esta função da um reload na página após 800 Milissegundo 
    window.setTimeout(function () {

        window.location.reload();

    }, 800);


}
```